# How do I search specific words through phonemes in the Pronouncing library for Python?

Tags: python, regex

I'm building a rhyme analyzer with the pronouncing library for Python which uses the CMU phoneme dictionary and in one part of my code, I have to search for words by phonemes. This can be done in the library with the method search() which takes regular expressions as input. But when I for example search "AY1", I get all words containing that sound, not just "I".

I tried using regular expressions like "xyz (.*?!)" and others, but that didn't seem to work.

This code:

```
print(pronouncing.search("AY1(.*?!)"))
```

gives an empty list as a return value, when I would want it to be something like ["aye", "eye", "I"] (eg. all the words that contain just this sound).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use the regex anchors `^` and `$`, which match the beginning and end of the line respectively.

```
pronouncing.search("^AY1$")
['ai', 'ay', 'aye', 'eye', 'i', 'i.']
```

Comment: I used something similar to that before which didn't work, this was exactly what I was looking for – thanks!